# Why am I getting a single value from my regex.exec?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a very simple code:

```
var allTypes = "restaurant|dentist";
var typeSplitter = new RegExp("([a-zA-Z]+)");
typeSplitter.exec(allTypes);
```

I want an array like this:

> ["restaurant", "dentist"]

But instead I get this:

> ["restaurant", "restaurant"]

I did test my regex [here](http://rubular.com/r/AI387UdKdC). I've been fiddling for way to long with this, probably something I don't know about

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just do this

```
allTypes.split('|');
// => ['restaurant', 'dentist']
```

`.split` can also take a regex; even though it's not necessary in this case

```
allTypes.split(/[|]/);
```

But if you really want to use regex to capture, you have to use `.match`

```
matches = allTypes.match(/([a-zA-Z]+)/g); // g = global modifier
```

Comment: just in case, I might need my regex (it gets more complex), am I using 'exec' correctly?

Comment: @code-gijoe: regex is a big club for something this simple.  Do the simplest thing that will work, and then fire up your regex if you need something more substantial.

Answer (score 4):

Because `exec` returns only one match and all captures. The first element is the full match. The second one the first capture (the first set of parentheses in your pattern). Since you have wrapped the entire pattern in parentheses, these values coincide (and your parentheses are unnecessary). Use `match` and a global modifier instead:

```
var result = "restaurant|dentist".match(/[a-zA-Z]+/g);
```

If you have a more complex pattern and you **do** need the capturing groups for every match, then `exec` is the way to go. But you still need to use the global modifier and run `exec` in a loop:

```
var regex = /your(Pattern)here/g;
var m;
while (m = regex.exec(input))
{
    var entireMatch = m[0];
    var firstCapture = m[1];
    // ...
    // process results
}
```

Comment: or if you really want to use new RegExp(), pass the global modifier with new RegExp(pattern,"g")